# Changing "Other Places" in Windows Explorer for XP

Tags: windows, explorer, shell-extensions

Where does "Other Places" in the panel of the left of Windows Explorer in XP come from (eg in the registry?) and is it possible to change? I can't seem to find anybody who has successfully changed this.

Comment: This is controlled by [group policy](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-the-places-bar-in-windows-xp/5630305).

Comment: I believe that's for the "Places" in the file open/save dialog.  I'm talking about "Other Places" in the regular explorer window: http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f196/overcracker/otherplaces.jpg

Comment: It's not clear how this is a programming question (unless you are trying to modify Explorer). The Other Places are hard-coded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw Visual Source Safe programmatically add a location to its file open dialog, though Kat added that that isn't where Kat needs it.  We can guess which companies would love to add Acrobat Reader, Windows Media Player, and Catalyst Control Center to the ordinary Explorer bar.  Someone who we don't know might actually have a legitimate use for it.

Comment: Yes is possible using undocumented SFVM message 83.

Comment: I miss wrote, this is possible only in namespace extension. :-)